# ERROR ClassNotFoundException: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atletas

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jframe

Necesito ayuda urgente, me sale este error:

> may 22, 2018 7:56:34 AM ventanas.inscripciones
>   btn_guardarActionPerformed GRAVE: null
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atletas

Es un programa donde registra atletas y luego debe mostrar los datos de 
cada uno de ellos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé con todo ya no se que mas hacer, si alguien por aquí tiene una respuesta se lo agradecería 
le adjunto el código

```
package ventanas;

import clases.Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;


public class inscripciones extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     Connection con= null;
     Statement stmt= null;

    public inscripciones() {
        initComponents();
        this.setTitle("INSCRIPCIONES");
        this.setLocation(220,100);
        this.setResizable(false);
        ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Valeria\\Documents\\java\\NetBeansProjects\\atletas\\src\\imagenes\\IND.png");
        this.setIconImage(icono.getImage());
    }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_ci = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_apellido = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_telefono = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_nombre = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane5 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2002 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane6 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_direccion = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane7 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane7 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane8 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2000 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane9 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2001 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btn_regresar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_guardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmb_sexo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        txt_ci.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_ciKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txt_ci);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 190, 130, -1));

        txt_apellido.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_apellidoKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txt_apellido);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 150, 130, -1));

        txt_telefono.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_telefonoKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(txt_telefono);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 110, 130, -1));

        txt_nombre.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_nombreKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(txt_nombre);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 110, 130, -1));

        jScrollPane5.setViewportView(txt_2002);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(400, 260, 50, -1));

        jScrollPane6.setViewportView(txt_direccion);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 150, 130, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Nombre:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 110, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Apellido:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 150, -1, -1));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("C.I:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 190, -1, -1));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel6.setText("Telefono:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 110, -1, -1));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel7.setText("Dirección:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 150, -1, -1));

        jLabel8.setText("ID:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(540, 80, -1, 20));

        jTextPane7.setEditable(false);
        jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTextPane7);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(560, 80, 20, 20));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 204));
        jLabel9.setText("Marcas");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 180, -1, -1));

        jScrollPane8.setViewportView(txt_2000);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(400, 220, 50, -1));

        jScrollPane9.setViewportView(txt_2001);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(520, 220, 50, -1));

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jLabel10.setText("2000");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 220, -1, -1));

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 204));
        jLabel11.setText("2001");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(470, 220, -1, -1));

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jLabel12.setText("2002");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 260, -1, -1));

        btn_regresar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        btn_regresar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        btn_regresar.setText("Regresar");
        btn_regresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_regresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btn_regresar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 330, -1, -1));

        btn_guardar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        btn_guardar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        btn_guardar.setText("Guardar");
        btn_guardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_guardarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btn_guardar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 330, -1, -1));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Ingresar los datos del Atleta:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 10, -1, -1));

        cmb_sexo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Seleccione", "Femenino ", "Masculino" }));
        getContentPane().add(cmb_sexo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 230, -1, -1));

        jLabel13.setText("Sexo:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 230, -1, -1));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/SLATO.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 670, 390));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn_regresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Menuopciones Menuopciones= new Menuopciones();
        Menuopciones.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                            

    private void txt_nombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        char validar= evt.getKeyChar();
     if (Character.isDigit(validar)){
         getToolkit().beep();

         evt.consume();
     }
    }                                   

    private void txt_apellidoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        char validar= evt.getKeyChar();
     if (Character.isDigit(validar)){
         getToolkit().beep();

         evt.consume();
     }
    }                                     

    private void txt_ciKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        char c= evt.getKeyChar();
      if ( c<'0' || c>'9') evt.consume();
    }                               

    private void txt_telefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
       char c= evt.getKeyChar();
      if ( c<'0' || c>'9') evt.consume();
    }                                     

    private void btn_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

     String cadena2,cadena3,cadena4,cadena5,cadena6,cadena7,cadena8,cadena9,cadena10;

        cadena2 = txt_nombre.getText();
        cadena3 = txt_apellido.getText();
        cadena4 = txt_ci.getText();
        cadena5 = cmb_sexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cadena6 = txt_telefono.getText();
        cadena7 = txt_direccion.getText();
        cadena8 = txt_2000.getText();
        cadena9 = txt_2001.getText();
        cadena10= txt_2002.getText();


        if (txt_nombre.getText().equals("") || (txt_apellido.getText().equals("")) || (txt_ci.getText().equals("")) || (cmb_sexo.getSelectedItem().equals(null)) || (txt_telefono.getText().equals(""))
           || (txt_direccion.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2000.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2001.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2002.getText().equals(""))) {

            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Debe llenar todos los campos \n","AVISO!",javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            txt_nombre.requestFocus();

       Conexion conn= new Conexion();
       Connection Connection = conn.getConnection();


      } 
        else {
        try {


            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atletas";
            String usuario = "root";
            String contraseña = "";

             Class.forName(url).newInstance(); 
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,contraseña); 
             if ( con != null ) 
                    System.out.println("Se ha establecido una conexión a la base de datos " +  
                                       "\n " + url ); 

                  stmt = con.createStatement(); 
                  stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO juegos VALUES('" + 0 + "','"+cadena2+"','"+cadena3+"','"+cadena4+"','"+cadena5+"','"+cadena6+"','"+cadena7+"','"+cadena8+"','"+cadena9+"','"+cadena10+"')");
                  System.out.println("Los valores han sido agregados a la base de datos ");



        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

       } 
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    stmt.close();
                } catch ( Exception e ) { 
                         System.out.println( "ClassNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
         javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Registro exitoso! \n","AVISO!",javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        this.txt_nombre.setText("");
        this.txt_apellido.setText("");
        this.txt_ci.setText("");
        this.txt_telefono.setText("");
        this.txt_direccion.setText("");
        this.txt_2000.setText("");
        this.txt_2001.setText("");
        this.txt_2002.setText("");




    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new inscripciones().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo

```
Class.forName(url).newInstance();
```

donde url es la cadena de conexión a tu BD. Obviamente, eso está mal (por eso te lanza el ClassNotFound, porque no encuentra ninguna clase en el classpath cuyo nombre sea "jdbc:mysql..."). Dado que estás usando MySQL, deberías hacer

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: Gracias.. Ya me dice que conecto a la base de datos pero ahora me sale este error, realmente soy nueva en esto y pues estoy aprendiendo te lo agradecería mucho.  java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Eso debes plantearlo como otra pregunta, puesto que nada tiene que ver ya con el problema que has descrito aquí. Por el error mostrado, todo apunta a que no estás proporcionando el número de valores correcto al insert, pero sólo con ese mensaje de error no es posible darte una ayuda más detallada. Marca esta respuesta como la correcta y abre una nueva pregunta.